# Is ad watching and earning halal?

Tags: halal-haram, fatwa

Many websites pay its users to see its ads. They get some revenue and give some of it to its visitors. Is this revenue and earning halal. I have saw many muslims and some of my colleagues doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untill it won't comply with advertisers policies it is haram to earn by watching ads. An advertiser advertises his product with intention to promote it not to make aware someone.

If the advertiser himself is paying users to watch his ads then it's halal.